# Добавить класс кнопке при клике

Tags: javascript, jquery

В `id="convert-json-to-html-tree-sets"` подгружаю форму с инпутами и кнопками к каждому инпуту

```
<div id="ikz-settings-sets">
 <div id="convert-json-to-html-tree-sets"></div>
```

Есть подключаемый файл к странице с ф-цией генерации нужной структуры `html`для
`id="ikz-settings-sets"`

Сама ф-ция

```
     function convertJsonToHtmlTree_Sets(obj, typeOfDevice,
     nameOfKey,    initialMasDeviceSettings, ikz35Key) {
               var huck.push(nameOfKey + key);
   var str = str +'<input id="' + nameOfKey + key + '"  >' + '</div>' +      
      '<div id="settings-for-device-' + nameOfKey + key +   '"' + 
    'class="button-other"></div>';       


                    return str;

                   }
```

На странице вызываю эту ф-цию

```
   $('#convert-json-to-html-tree-sets').append( convertJsonToHtmlTree_Sets(result.device_settings.bonding, typeOfDevice, '', initialMasDeviceSettingsSets) );
```

Мне необходимо, чтобы при клике кнопке добавлялся нужный класс `".button-not-press"`

```
  for ( var i = 0; i < huck.length; i++ ) {
        var huck2 = $('#settings-for-device-' + huck[i]);

            $('#ikz-settings-sets input').on('input', function() { 
                        $(this).addClass('changedInput'); 

                            currentDeviceSettingsSets = ( $('#ikz-settings-sets').get(0).outerHTML ); 


                            if ( initialDeviceSettingsSets != currentDeviceSettingsSets ) { 


                                    $('#settings-for-device-' + huck[i]).addClass('button-not-press'); 
                            } else { 
                                    $('#settings-for-device-' + huck[i]).removeClass('button-not-press'); 
                            }   

                    }); 

                }
```

Comment: Очень читаемый код

Comment: `$('#ikz-settings-sets input').on('input', function() {` замените на `$('#ikz-settings-sets').on('input', 'input', function() {`

Comment: Не срабатывает, ..именно здесь в этой стр-ре и ломается

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в коде заключается в том, что навешивание события через запись -

```js
$('#ikz-settings-sets').on('input', function() {})
```

Приводит к тому, что события подписываются только для уже существующих DOM элементов. Вам необходимо переписать установку слушателя событий в стиле

```js
$('#ikz-settings-sets input').on('input', 'input', function(event) {...})
```

в таком варианте записи событие будет проверяться динамически для всех элементов. От себя я бы рекомендовал вешать событие не на сам тег `input` а создать для этого отдельный classname и использовать его.

Comment: видимо, что то делаю не так. добавил вашу запись. Добавление класса кнопке не происходит.

Comment: Добавление к тегу класса происходит $(this).addClass('changedInput'); но кнопке нет;

Comment: не рекомендую использовать this. Попробуйте так `event.target.classList.add('chandeginput')`